# Grails - adding runtime mixin to Object class via BootStrap does not work

Tags: grails, groovy

I've defined a mixin which I'd like to apply to all objects in my application so I thought defining it on the `Object` class would be best. In order for the mixin to be applied from the start, I thought about setting it via `BootStrap.groovy`. However, that doesn't seem to be effective because when I try to call the method defined in the mixin, from any object within the context of a unit test, I get `MissingPropertyException`.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Here's a sample:

```
class MyMixin {

    def sayHello() {
        println "Hello!"
    }

}
```

`BootStrap.groovy` looks like this:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    Object.class.mixin(MyMixin)
}

def destroy = {}
```

Comment: if you call `"abc".sayHello()` right in the bootstrap, is it working?

Comment: Yes. Check [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204578/grails-adding-runtime-mixin-to-object-class-via-bootstrap-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment37371409_24204930) for more info.

Comment: so, it smells like ClassLoader-issue

Comment: I'm not sure why `BootStrap` is called only *after* my tests...

Comment: try running integration tests

Comment: Are you sure your BootStrap is being run after your unit tests?  It surprises me that it is run at all.

Comment: @injecteer BootStrap is run for integration tests.  I don't think it is supposed to be run for unit tests, but he says it is.  I will look into it.

Comment: I bet the unit tests are running, then BootStrap is being executed in preparation for running integration tests.  If you run "grails test-app unit:", I expect that BootStrap is not run.

Comment: @injecteer that's `grails test-app integration` right? They're passing. So should I just permanently move them as integration tests? @Jeff I'm not sure but I can see the message getting printed when running unit tests.

Comment: I doubt that the message is being printed when running unit tests.  It is probably running in preparation for running integration tests.  If BootStrap is running when you run unit tests, that is a bug.  Is it run when you do "grails test-app unit:"?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown well, they're not getting printed when I explicitly run with `unit:` option.

Comment: That is because BootStrap is not run for unit tests.  BootStrap is run for integration tests.  If you run "grails test-app", your unit tests are run without having run BootStrap.  Then, after that, BootStrap is run as part of the process of preparing your integration tests to run.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Could any one of you add that as answer so I can accept? I'll update the question with additional information based on these comments.

Comment: As I suggested in my answer below, the problem is that you are trying to take advantage of the mixin in a context where the mixin has not been applied.

Comment: As an aside, I would not turn this into an integration test just to test this. Integration tests bring a bunch of other stuff into the runtime and you don't need to pay that cost. I would create a helper class that does the metaprogramming and call that from your BootStrap and also call it as part of the setup from a unit test which wants to test those effects.

Comment: That makes sense. How about I define a method in `BootStrap` that I can call from within the unit tests, a static method like `BootStrap.setUpMixins()`?

Comment: @injecteer Regarding "it smells like ClassLoader-issue"... I don't think this has anything to do with class loaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there looks valid and should work.  I don't know what you mean by "I try to call the method defined in the mixin from a test object" but I suspect you are either invoking the method incorrectly or that you are executing that code in a context where your BootStrap has not been run.

**EDIT:**

BootStrap is not (and is not supposed to be) executed for your unit tests.  I think that is the problem.

Comment: This seems to be what's happening. When I said invoking the mixin method from a test object, I meant invoking the mixin method from an object created within the context of a test. After trying to invoke the method in `BootStrap`, I can see the message printed *after* the test.

Comment: That is the issue.  You are expecting the mixin to be applied in your unit test environment but it isn't because BootStrap is not (and is not supposed to be) run before your unit tests run.

Comment: It should be noted that Groovy runtime mixins have been deprecated and replaced with traits in Groovy 2.3 and in general should not be used